# chaining line by line writing/reading of pipes in Python with subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, pipe

I have the following code which appears to work, for chaining pipes together in python with subprocess while reading / writing to them line by line (without using `communicate()` upfront). The code just calls a Unix command (`mycmd`), reads its output, then writes that to the stdin of another Unix command (`next_cmd`), and redirects the output of that last command to a file.

```
    # some unix command that uses a pipe: command "a"
    # writes to stdout and "b" reads it and writes to stdout
    mycmd = "a | b" 
    mycmd_proc = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, shell=True,
                                  stdin=sys.stdin,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    # nextCmd reads from stdin, and I'm passing it mycmd's output
    next_cmd = "nextCmd -stdin"
    output_file = open(output_filename, "w")
    next_proc = subprocess.Popen(next_cmd, shell=True,
                                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stdout=output_file)
    for line in iter(mycmd.stdout.readline, ''):
        # do something with line
        # ...
        # write it to next command
        next_proc.stdin.write(line)
    ### If I wanted to call another command here that passes next_proc output
    ### line by line to another command, would I need
    ### to call next_proc.communicate() first?
    next_proc.communicate()
    output_file.close()
```

This appears to work, and it only calls `communicate()` at the end of the command.

I'm trying to extend this code to add another command so you can do:

```
mycmd1 | mycmd2 | mycmd3 > some_file
```

meaning: line by line, read output of mycmd1 from Python, *process* the line, feed it to mycmd2, read mycmd2's output and line by line *process it* and feed it to mycmd3 which in turns puts its output in `some_file`. Is this possible or is this bound to end in deadlock/blocking/unflushed buffers? Note that I'm not just calling three unix commands as a pipe since I want to intervene with Python in between and post-process each command's output line by line before feeding it to the next command.

I want to avoid calling communicate and loading all the output into memory - instead I want to parse it line by line. thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this example in the manual?  http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: @zigg: sure but it does not answer the question. I am not just making a pipe, I want to read from one pipe and write to the other, not just call unix commands that happen to make a pipe. It's important for me to know at what point in reading/writing a block or unflushed buffer can occur.

Comment: My apologies; you're right.  I should have read your question more closely.

Answer (score 1):

This should handle an arbitrary number of commands:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def processFirst(out):
    return out

def processSecond(out):
    return out

def processThird(out):
    return out

commands = [("a|b", processFirst), ("nextCmd -stdin", processSecond), ("thirdCmd", processThird)]

previous_output = None
for cmd,process_func in commands:
    if previous_output is None:
        stdin = sys.stdin
    else:
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                            stdin = stdin,
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    if previous_output is not None:
        proc.stdin.write(previous_output)

    out,err = proc.communicate()
    out = process_func(out)
    previous_output = out
```

Just add any command you want to run to the list of commands along with the function that should process its output. The output from the last command will end up being in `previous_output` at the end of the loop.

To avoid any deadlocking/buffering/etc issues, you simply run each command to completion using `proc.communicate()` which will return the output(instead of reading it directly as in your example). You then feed that into the next command before letting it run to completion, so on and so forth.

Edit: Just noticed that you don't want to use `communicate()` upfront and that you want to react line by line. I will edit my answer in a bit to address that

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486717/python-select-doesnt-signal-all-input-from-pipe) provides an example on how to read line-by-line from a pipe without blocking using `select.select()`.

Below is an example that uses it for your particular case:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import select
import os

class LineReader(object):
    def __init__(self, fd, process_func):
        self._fd = fd
        self._buf = ''
        self._process_func = process_func
        self.next_proc = None

    def fileno(self):
        return self._fd

    def readlines(self):
        data = os.read(self._fd, 4096)
        if not data:
            # EOF
            if self.next_proc is not None:
                self.next_proc.stdin.close()
            return None
        self._buf += data
        if '\n' not in data:
            return []
        tmp = self._buf.split('\n')
        tmp_lines, self._buf = tmp[:-1], tmp[-1]
        lines = []
        for line in tmp_lines:
            lines.append(self._process_func(line))
            if self.next_proc is not None:
                self.next_proc.stdin.write("%s\n" % lines[-1])

        return lines

def processFirst(line):
    return line

def processSecond(line):
    return line

def processThird(line):
    return line

commands = [("a|b", processFirst), ("nextCmd -stdin", processSecond), ("thirdCmd", processThird)]

readers = []
previous_reader = None
for cmd,process_func in commands:
    if previous_reader is None:
        stdin = sys.stdin
    else:
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                            stdin = stdin,
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

    if previous_reader is not None:
        previous_reader.next_proc = proc

    previous_reader = LineReader(proc.stdout.fileno(), process_func)
    readers.append(previous_reader)


while readers:
    ready,_,_  = select.select(readers, [], [], 10.0)
    for stream in ready:
        lines = stream.readlines()
        if lines is None:
            readers.remove(stream)
```